# webfilter do subscribe in filter logic

Tags: spring-webflux, reactor

I'm using webflux.

There's a warning from intellij idea.

warning message: `calling subscribe in non-blocking scope`

Is there anyway to subscribe the response mono correctly?
(I don't want to affect an original request.)

```java
@Slf4j
@Component
public class CustomWebFilter implements WebFilter {

    @Override
    public Mono<Void> filter(ServerWebExchange exchange, WebFilterChain chain) {
        Mono<String> response = getAsyncResponse();
        mono.subscribe();

        return chain.filter(exchange);
    }
}
```

Comment: The one starting the request is the subscriber. Your service is most likely a producer so no you should not subscribe. You should only subscribe if your service is the one initiating and consuming the call

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not `subscribe()` but you need to construct reactive flow and WebFlux will subscribe to it. In addition, `subscribe` is async operation and your filter will not work as expected.

```
@Slf4j
@Component
public class CustomWebFilter implements WebFilter {

    @Override
    public Mono<Void> filter(ServerWebExchange exchange, WebFilterChain chain) {
        return getAsyncResponse()
                .flatMap(respone -> chain.filter(exchange));
    }
}
```

Comment: How about returning `chain.filter(exchange)).then(getAsyncResponse().then();`?

Comment: if you don't need response you could use `then` as well. 
`chain.filter(exchange)).then(getAsyncResponse().then())` or `getAsyncResponse().then(chain.filter(exchange))

Comment: When I tested, original response waited for getAsyncResponse() method.
Is there anyway to response original request in advance, not waiting for getting asyncResponse()?