# How to create http interceptors in Spring boot web flux

Tags: java, spring-boot, jwt, spring-webflux

I want to add HTTP interceptors in my spring boot web flux application to make a call to DB every time(to check if a token exists) before calling a few endpoints. There's no support of HandlerInterceptor in web flux, I tried filter available in web flux, but that isn't working, so I tried adding it SecurityContextRepository file.
Following is the code,

```
@Component
public class SecurityContextRepository implements ServerSecurityContextRepository {

    private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;
    
    @Autowired
    private TokenRepository tokenRepository;
    
    public SecurityContextRepository(AuthenticationManager authenticationManager) {
        this.authenticationManager = authenticationManager;
    }

    @Override
    public Mono<Void> save(ServerWebExchange swe, SecurityContext sc) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet.");
    }

    @Override
    public Mono<SecurityContext> load(ServerWebExchange swe) {
        return Mono.justOrEmpty(swe.getRequest().getHeaders().getFirst(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION))
            .filter(authHeader -> authHeader.startsWith("Bearer "))
            .flatMap(authHeader -> {
                String authToken = authHeader.substring(7);
                Mono<Token> tokenResponse = (Mono<Token>) tokenRepository.checkIfTokenExists(authToken);
                Mono<String> finalToken = tokenResponse.map(u -> u.getToken().toString());
                if(finalToken.toString() != null || !finalToken.toString().isEmpty() || !finalToken.toString().isBlank()) {
                      Authentication auth = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(authToken, authToken);
                      return this.authenticationManager.authenticate(auth).map(SecurityContextImpl::new);
                } else {
                    throw new ExpiredJwtException(null, null, "Token is expired");
                }
            });
    }
    
}
```

Am I taking the right approach? As I see examples, where filters are used to count the time taken by an API. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: WebFlux provides two types of filters: WebFilters and HandlerFilterFunctions. Here is a small example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71794064/webfilter-do-subscribe-in-filter-logic/71860184#71860184

Comment: @Alex thank you for your response, I found the solution, it worked with WebFilters